# What is wrong with this SQL DELETE FROM syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to delete 96k records.

## delete all the records in table xoops_bb_posts_text pages that don't have a have a matching post_id to xoops_bb_posts

This query worked returning 91k records:

```
SELECT *  
   FROM xoops_bb_posts_text t  
   WHERE not exists (
       select post_id 
           from xoops_bb_posts p 
           WHERE p.post_id = t.post_id 
   );
```

when I tried to delete those records I got a syntax error, but I don't see it.

```
DELETE FROM xoops_bb_posts_text t  
WHERE not exists (
    select post_id 
       from xoops_bb_posts p 
    WHERE p.post_id = t.post_id 
);
```

Where is the error?

Error

SQL query: Documentation

```
DELETE FROM xoops_bb_posts_text t 
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (  
      SELECT post_id  
         FROM xoops_bb_posts p  
         WHERE p.post_id = t.post_id  
)
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE not exists (select post_id from xoops_bb_posts p WHERE
>   p.post_id = t.post_' at line 2

Comment: Ah, my eyes! Please work on your code formatting next time.

Comment: I don't know mysql, but my guess is that the `SELECT post_id` in the subquery also needs an alias, since the queried table is aliased, and post_id is ambigious. (so:: `"select p.post_id`). `Select *` would also do the trick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To me, this problem is more easily solved by using a `delete` statement with a an `outer join` and looking for the rows that had no match. Something like this:

```
delete t from xoops_bb_posts_text as t
left outer join xoops_bb_posts as p
on p.post_id = t.post_id
where p.post_id is null;
```

or simply changing your query:

```
DELETE t
FROM xoops_bb_posts_text t  
WHERE not exists 
      (select post_id from xoops_bb_posts p WHERE p.post_id = t.post_id );
```

Comment: The asker isn't looking for a new way to build his query, he is simply asking what the syntax error is.

Answer (score 10):

If you alias tables in a delete call, you have to use the alias as the argument:

`DELETE alias FROM tablerealname as ALIAS ...`

So in OP's original question, he simply has to add the alias after DELETE:

```
DELETE t FROM xoops_bb_posts_text as t WHERE NOT EXISTS (  
SELECT post_id  
FROM xoops_bb_posts as p  
WHERE p.post_id = t..post_id  
)
```

Comment: You _can_ alias tables in a `delete` statement. See [MySQL delete docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/delete.html#id920676) and [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8403456/166339).

Comment: Updated to reflect this (turns out you can, just you have to use the "as" keyword and can't just use the space syntax as in SELECT)

Comment: You _do not_ have to use the `as` keyword. It's optional. You could remove the keyword `as` from the query and it would still work.

Comment: No, the `AS` is not the issue here. You just have to use `DELETE t FROM ...`, with or without `AS`.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Updating my answer accordingly.  I am less familiar with aliases than I'd like to be.

Comment: @Asaph-I'm pretty sure there is nowhere in the doc you linked to that uses alias' without `AS` The statement you quote is using `t1` and `t2` as full table names not alias'. The only reference to alias' is in the code `DELETE t1 AS a1, t2 AS a2 FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 WHERE a1.id=a2.id;` which as you can see uses `AS`

Comment: @anothershrubery: In my comment on your answer, I initially quoted the wrong SQL statement. Sorry about that. I've since updated my comment. Have another look at my updated comment for the search text of a `delete` query using aliases. Also, even though the docs use the `AS` keyword in their examples, it's optional and could be removed and the queries would still work.

Comment: Yeah I meant to post in this answer not the other one, but it is in response to the third comment in this answer, where you say "You do not have to use the `AS` keyword." Doesn't matter really, it wasn't my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot alias table names in single-table [DELETE in MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html). You need to use full table name, like this:

```
DELETE FROM xoops_bb_posts_text
WHERE not exists (select post_id from xoops_bb_posts p WHERE p.post_id = xoops_bb_posts_text.post_id );
```

Comment: You _can_ alias tables in a `delete` statement. See [MySQL delete docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/delete.html#id920676) and [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8403456/166339).

Comment: @Asaph are you sure it would work in mysql? From the syntax chart at the link in my answer, it does not look like mysql understands the aliasing syntax available in other rdbms-s.

Comment: If you actually read the complete page of the MySQL docs that _you_ linked to, you'll see that it's true. Search the page linked in your answer for `DELETE t1 FROM test AS t1, test2 WHERE ...`.

Comment: @Asaph The sample you quoted is not an example of aliasing: it's just tables that happen to be called `t1` and `t2`. All examples of table aliasing there are shown in conjunction with multi-table syntax, and all these examples reference multiple tables.

Comment: In my initial comment on this answer, I mistakenly quoted the wrong search text. I've since updated my comment. Have a look at my updated comment for an example of a `delete` query that uses aliases. Also, what's wrong with referencing multiple tables? It seems to me that it's perfectly appropriate here given that the question deals with multiple tables.

Comment: @Asaph there's nothing inherently wrong with deletes referencing multiple tables, except the OP asked where his syntax error was, not how to rewrite his query while keeping a table alias. To that end, the second part of your answer is significantly more useful than the first part: it gently fixes the syntax error, rather than producing a different query.

Answer (score 0):

You can not specify a table alias in the delete statement.

Comment: You _can_ alias tables in a `delete` statement. See [MySQL delete docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/delete.html#id920676) and [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8403456/166339).

Comment: You're right, but not with the ordinary delete statement. You need the multi table syntax as in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

From my comment:

```
DELETE FROM xoops_bb_posts_text t  
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
      FROM xoops_bb_posts p 
     WHERE p.post_id = t.post_id 
);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_student1` (
  `stud_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `stud_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `stream_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `s_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`stud_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY ('stream_id')
        REFERENCES tbl_stream ('stream_id')
        ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Answer (score -2):

i don't know the syntax "EXISTS". I think its better to use "in" and "not in"

Try:

```
DELETE FROM xoops_bb_posts_text WHERE post_id not in (SELECT post_id  FROM xoops_bb_posts)
```