# Hibernate native sql table not found error

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

I'm trying to run a native SQL delete in a hibernate session, but i get an exception complaining about the table alias. If I run the sql query in a SQL client, then it works fine.

```
String sql = 'delete c from child c join parent p on c.parent_id=p.id where p.some_id = :someId'
SQLQuery deleteQuery = sessionFactory.currentSession.createSQLQuery(sql)
deleteQuery.setParameter( 'someId', some.id.longValue() )
deleteQuery.executeUpdate()
```

Exception thrown in my unit test:

```
[main] ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Table "C" not found; SQL statement:

delete  c  from child  c  join parent p on c.parent_id=p.id where p.some_id = ? [42102-164]

org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.NativeSQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:219)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.executeNativeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1310)
at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.executeUpdate(SQLQueryImpl.java:396)
at org.hibernate.Query$executeUpdate.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
```

Any suggestions on why this doesn't work through hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

**(EDITED)**

Using names of tables better.

```
String sql = 'DELETE child FROM child INNER JOIN parent ON child.parent_id = parent.id WHERE parent.some_id = :someId';
```

**ADD**

This is a example code (my) adapted for you:

```
...

public boolean eliminar( Child some_id )
{
    boolean result  = false;
    Session session = null;
    Transaction rs  = null;

    try
    {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        rs = session.beginTransaction();
        rs.setTimeout(5);

        String query_string = "DELETE child FROM child INNER JOIN parent ON child.parent_id = parent.id WHERE parent.some_id = :someId";
        query_string.setParameter( 'someId', some_id );
        Query q = session.createQuery(query_string);
        q.executeUpdate();

        rs.commit();

        result = true;
    }
    catch(RuntimeException e)
    {
        try
        {
            rs.rollback();
        }
        catch(RuntimeException rbe)
        {
            System.out.println(rbe.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
        session.close();
    }
    return result;
}
...
```

Comment: that errors with: ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Syntax error in SQL statement "delete from child c join[*] parent p on c.parent_id=p.id where p.some_id = ?"; SQL statement:
delete from child c join parent p on c.parent_id=p.id where p.some_id = ? [42000-164]

Comment: I edit my entry, try again with new query. I replace alias for names of tables. The error is that mysql no matches the table.

Comment: ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Syntax error in SQL statement "delete child from[*] child inner join parent p on child.some_id=p.id where p.some_id = ?"; SQL statement:

Comment: mmm, it is another message. I find this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403388/what-is-wrong-with-this-sql-delete-from-syntax

Comment: As previously stated, the SQL statement is correct as it works in a SQL client. For some reason, hibernate does appear to like it. Have I got the code correct to run the native SQL statement? Any possible hibernate properties i may be missing?

Comment: I paste part of my code adapted for you. If you want maybe remove lines of transation.